# SwiftUI: How to enable ScrollView only when device is in landscape mode?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to disable scroll view when application is not in landscape mode, but I don't know how to do it in SwiftUI, does anyone have a solution for that. I tried to add empty array for the axes property when device is in landscape mode, but that is no working:

```
ScrollView(axes, showsIndicators: false) {
    VStack(spacing: 10) {
        Text("Something 1")
        Text("Something 2")
        Text("Something 3")
        Text("Something 4")
        Text("Something 5")
    }
}.padding(.top, 10)

///...

private var axes: Axis.Set {
    return UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape ? [] : .vertical
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some useful code on Hacking With Swift for detecting device orientation changes in SwiftUI: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-detect-device-rotation

However, I had to alter it slightly to get a reliable first value. Here's what I ended up with for a view modifier:

```
struct DeviceRotationViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    let action: (UIDeviceOrientation) -> Void
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onAppear {
                action(UIDevice.current.orientation)
            }
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification).dropFirst()) { _ in
                action(UIDevice.current.orientation)
            }
    }
}

extension View {
    func onRotate(perform action: @escaping (UIDeviceOrientation) -> Void) -> some View {
        self.modifier(DeviceRotationViewModifier(action: action))
    }
}
```

Then, in your `View`, you can conditionally display a `ScrollView` or just a `VStack`, depending on this orientation:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var orientation = UIDeviceOrientation.unknown
    
    @ViewBuilder var subView : some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            Text("Something 1")
            Text("Something 2")
            Text("Something 3")
            Text("Something 4")
            Text("Something 5")
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if orientation.isLandscape {
                VStack {
                    subView
                    Spacer()
                }
            } else {
                ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                    subView
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(.top, 10)
        .onRotate { newOrientation in
            orientation = newOrientation
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, yeah this is a solution, I just found this code on Hacking With Swift, a minute before I saw you answer, yeah this is a solution, but I think this is a bit hacky because I will display totally different view for different orientation, it will be better if there is a way to just disable a Scroll View if there is landscape orientation.

But this will work totally, thank you very much for your help, I will try and then mark this as a good solution.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a totally different view -- that's why I split out all of the common components into `subView` -- it's just a different container for it.

Comment: I have a problem when I use this approach when going to landscape mode after I redirect to some different view in the tab bar, everything is crashed, I then have everything moved up like a totally bad view, for some reason, I think I have to send orientation property when I go to redirect to some other view. When I go back and use UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape, then everything working just fine,...

Comment: For some reason, I found that when the device is in landscape mode and I just lunch an app, the orientation property is false even if device was in landscape mode, I don't know why is that, do you have any clue about that?

Comment: I found that to be the case with the original Hacking with Swift code, but not my modified version.

Comment: For me, it's not working at all, so I had to use `(UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.windowScene?.interfaceOrientation.isLandscape ?? false)` this works well for me.

Comment: I will mark your solution as the best answer, but I just want to mention that I read a lot of resources from Apple design instructions, and actually, they don't like you to think about landscape design a lot, you have to design your app in a way that application actually very well support all types of screens so you don't have to check all the time what is Device orientation. But thank you @jnpdx for help, a lot.

Comment: Yes, that recommendation from Apple is a good one to follow, for sure!

Answer (score 0):

there is a disabled option, maybe you could use:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var orientation = UIDeviceOrientation.unknown
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack(spacing: 10) {
                Text("Something 1")
                Text("Something 2")
                Text("Something 3")
                Text("Something 4")
                Text("Something 5")
            }
        }.disabled(!orientation.isLandscape)
        .padding(.top, 10)
        .onRotate { newOrientation in
            orientation = newOrientation
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this will disable interaction with any child elements inside the scroll view, right? Which may or may not be an issue for the OP

Comment: Yeah this can be an issue